# Elasticsearch query_string - exact phrase issue

Tags: elasticsearch

Assuming I have an index, and I added a few documents, using this statement:

```
POST test/item/_bulk
{"id": 1, "text": "one two"}
{"id": 2, "text": "one two three"}
{"id": 3, "text": "three one two"}
{"id": 4, "text": "three one two four"}
{"id": 5, "text": "one two|"}
{"id": 6, "text": "|one two"}
{"id": 7, "text": "|one two|"}
{"id": 8, "text": "one|two"}
{"id": 9, "text": "one| two"}
{"id": 10, "text": "one |two"}
{"id": 11, "text": "one | two"}
```

I want this search:

```
GET test/item/_search
{
    "query": 
    {
        "query_string": 
        {
            "query": "\"one two\"",
            "fields": ["text"],
            "analyze_wildcard": "true",
            "allow_leading_wildcard": "true",
            "default_operator": "AND"
        }
    }
}
```

to return documents **1-7**.

I tried various analyzers and tokenizers (std, whitespace, etc.), both on the documents and on the query, but none of them gave me the wanted results.

For example, the std analyzer returned all of the documents and the whitespace analyzer only returned 1-4.

Is there an analyzer/tokenizer/parameter that will return the wanted results?

**NOTE**: Just to make clear, my data consists of both short and **very** long strings with no common characteristics. The words (one, two, three, four) and the sign (|) I gave as examples are just for convenience, and can be replaced with any other words and non-word characters.

Answer (score 0):

you should use range query. 
Official docs:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: The range query is irrelevant for my needs, my data consists of strings with no common characteristics. The "one"/ "two"/ "three"/"four" is just an example. I added a note to clarify this. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try Pattern analyzer to analyze your data. It allows you to specify a RegEx to define a pattern to split your text.

You should create a custom analyzer and define a pattern to tokenize your data.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/custom-analyzers.html

Comment: Is there any danger of performance issues when using the pattern tokenizer on very long strings?

Comment: I can't confirm that,  but maybe there is. But I think it is better to be done on elasticsearch rather then doing it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, i don't understand you yesterday.
Exist one solution, but is it optimize, i don't sure:
at first you should create dynamic template, and set for your field not_analyzed mode:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_template/template1' -d '
{
    "template":"test_*",
    "mappings": {
        "item": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "strings": {
                        "mapping": { 
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "match_mapping_type": "string"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aliases": {}
}'
```

Then i inserted next rows:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test_1/item/1 -d '{ "text": "one two"}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test_1/item/2 -d '{ "text": "one two three"}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test_1/item/3 -d '{ "text": "three one two"}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test_1/item/4 -d '{ "text": "three one two    four"}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test_1/item/5 -d '{ "text": "one two|"}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test_1/item/6 -d '{ "text": "|one two"}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test_1/item/7 -d '{ "text": "|one two|"}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test_1/item/8 -d '{ "text": "one|two"}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test_1/item/9 -d '{ "text": "one| two"}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test_1/item/10 -d '{ "text": "one |two"}'
```

And with wildcard query you can return necessary rows:

```
curl localhost:9200/test_1/_search -d '
{
"query": {
    "match" : {
        "test" : "one two"
    }
}
}'
```

And this query return 7 rows:

```
nugusbayevkk@mediator:/data/databases/elasticsearch-5.2.2/bin$ curl localhost:9200/test_1/_search?filter_path=hits.total -d '
{
"query": {
    "wildcard" : {
        "text" : "*one two*"
    }
}
}'
{"hits":{"total":7}}
```

?filter_path - let show some fields, in this case it show total existed rows.